# Eclipse Maven Build Issue: Failed to compile input schema(s)!

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e, jaxb2

I seem to be having a maven issue with my eclipse.  I have eclipse plugin m2e and Egit in my Juno eclipse version and they are up to date.  And BTW it does compile fine in eclipse and DOS mvn - but eclipse is still registering the issue.

The pom.xml section in question

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>0.8.3</version>
   <configuration>
      <catalog>src/main/resources/my-model.cat</catalog>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
      <execution>           //This is being highlighted as an error
         <id>generate-sources</id>
         <phase>generate-sources</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
               <schemaIncludes>
                  <!-- <include>a.xsd b.xsd c.xsd</include> -->
                  <include>*.xsd</include>
               </schemaIncludes>
         <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
         <writeCode>true</writeCode>
         <episode>true</episode>
         <episodeFile>${project.build.directory}/generate-sources/xjc/META-INF/my-model.episode</episodeFile>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

But I'm getting a problem that says:

```
Failed to compile input schema(s)! Error messages should have been provided.
(org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.8.3:generate:generate-sources:generate-sources)    pom.xml /myProj line 56 Maven Build Problem
```

That's all I'm getting - just a RED annoying problem, highlighted annotations in the explorers and a squiggly line in the pom file. No schema is marked or anything else.  I know its not stopping me from working and running maven but why is Eclipse and/or m2e doing this?

Thanks,
Kevin

EDIT:
my-model.cat file

```
PUBLIC "urn:com:myCom:myProj:model" "a.xsd"
PUBLIC "urn:com:myCom:myProj:operations" "b.xsd"
PUBLIC "urn:com:myCom:myProj:class" "c.xsd"
```

There's nothing much to it.

Comment: Could you provide an example XSD you want to process? Do you really have a catalog entry in `my-model.cat`? This seems to be copied from http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-Usingcatalogs.

Comment: Check your workspace installed JRE preferences. Make sure there JDKs, not JREs.

Comment: my-model file is basically this:

Comment: Added my-model.cat file in the EDIT above

Comment: Blackbuild:  Not sure what you mean.  My Preferences > Java > Installed JREs  has the value jre7   c:\Program Files\jdk1.7.0.45\jre. So it is a JDK jre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK - Resolved this. Appears that m2e has some connector some issues. Found this [link](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2e-jaxb2-connector/) that is the google code site for the m2e-jaxb2-connectors from eclipse labs.

Added this to the 'Install New Software' area and this issue and others (other people had continual building) all went away.   I guess this is a must-have plug-in for jaxb developers.

Kevin